# What alternatives to Bugzilla for Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, bugzilla

It looks like Bugzilla is being dropped from Debian and Ubuntu.
Are there alternate packages that provide similar services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where to start? There are so many. This Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_tracking_system) lists quite a few in the footer of the page.

Only want open source? Try this [list](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system/).

Of course if you still want to use Bugzilla you can always download and build it yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the hassle of downloading, compiling and manually installing - usually this is not just time consuming, but involves one or more magic steps that, three years later are lost as the person who set that up has left the company.
I'd much rather set up a VM and update the .deb files automatically as they become public. I'm looking for a supported Ubuntu bug tracking package.

Comment: @user73139: you want a tracker and information gets lost because it's not being tracked? How about filing bug/issue #1 as documentation of the tracker itself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is in fact being dropped from Debian. I can still see the package in Wheezy for example. It is called libwww-bugzilla-perl. Have you searched for that?

Comment: The description of `libwww-bugzilla-perl` says _WWW::Bugzilla is a Perl module that handles submission and updating of bug reports submitted to arbitrary Bugzilla installations_. It's not a replacement for the `bugzilla` squeeze package which provided a fully functional website.